# Print nested list, python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, printing

I have a nested list like this:

```
nestedList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I want to use a for-loop and print the two lists like this:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you’re looking for is a way to transpose a list of lists, e.g. [numpy.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: Numpy is a rather large dependency for such a small task.

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Use [`*nestedList`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack argument lists values and then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over them:

```
nestedList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

for a in zip(*nestedList):
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() in for loop and output should be like this :

```
(1,4)
(2,5)
(3,6)
```

or using simple code like this :

```
nestedList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

l1 = nestedList[0]
l2 = nestedList[1]

for i in range(3):
    print(l1[i],' ',l2[i])
```

output should be like this :

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use nested for loops to print as expected:

```
nestedlist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for i in range(len(nestedlist)-1):
    for j in range(len(nestedlist[i])):
        print(nl[i][j]," ",nl[i+1][j])
```

Output:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop and " ".join() mapping each int in the nested list to a str with map().

**Example:**

```py
>>> ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> for xs in ys:
...     print(" ".join(map(str, xs)))
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```